# ¿Cómo podría descargar un archivo a través de un iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

estoy intentando hacer que se descargue un archivo a través de un iframe dependiendo de si el usuario cumple con algunos requisitos (que no tenga seteado un elemento en el localStorage) dejo aquí mi code:

JavaScript:

```
    setInterval(function () {
            var ob = localStorage.getItem('install');

            if (ob == null) {

                localStorage.setItem('install', 'download');
                localStorage.setItem('install_c', 'Por privacidad y seguridad, hemos limitado las descargas a una por dispositivo.');
                localStorage.setItem('maniatica', 'yes');
                document.write("<iframe class='hidden' src='https://link.com'> width='0' height= '0' </iframe>");
            }
            else {
                localStorage.setItem('install_c', 'Por privacidad y seguridad, hemos limitado las descargas a una por dispositivo.');
            }
       
  }, 1000);
```

Codigo de Iframe:

```
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=./file.apk">

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

El problema de este code es que desaparecen todo el contenido de la web y solo se queda un cuadradito que es el iframe y la descarga. ¿Hay alguna forma de que no pase esto? Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Digamos que tienes un iframe

```
<iframe src="example.htm" name="page"></iframe>
```

Para que el navegador abra un enlace ahí dentro, debería funcionar el atributo `target` apuntando al nombre del iframe:

```
<a href="https://www.example.com/file.pdf" target="page">Archivo</a>
```